# Can't drag DrawerLayout from ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-listview, drawerlayout

I have the following `MainActivity` layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#EAEAEA" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The `fragment` I add on the `FrameLayout` contains a `ListView`. The problem is that I cannot drag the `DrawerLayout` from `ListView`, only if `ListView` is long enough to scroll (vertically).

Everything works well for the DrawerLayout, I have tried to open it using `openDrawer` and it works, I only can't open it by dragging from `ListView`. Is there any way to fix this?